# One provider for all entities or different according to needs?

Tags: domain-driven-design

I am trying to design in DDD the management of orders to a privider.

The order has to have the information of the provider to which i will order the items. Later I will add lines to the order. This lines will need to have information of the provider, but different than the data that I need for the provider of the order.

For the provider of the order I need the business ID, the name and the address but for the provider of the lines I need only the name.

So I am thinking that in that bounded context I could have two privders class, one with the information needed for the order and other provider for the prvider of the line. But I don't know if it is better, inside the context, to have only one provider that has all the information that could I need for all the classes that need the information of the provider.

Which is best option?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So from a business perspective, there is an entity "provider" which consists out of id, name and address.
And depending on the usage you sometimes need all data, sometimes only a few.

My thoughts:
If you depend your entity on its usage (having multiple entities of the same business thing for multiple, slightly different usages), then a new usage will result in an additional entity.
Thats a lot of additional work and duplicated code.
Therefore in general i would opt for one entity implementation for one business entity.

But no rule without exceptions.
If an entity contains critical data and the entity is coming around a lot (crossing system borders) but only in few places the critical data is needed, then it may be a thought to have a implementation only containing the non-critical data and one with all data.
That way the critical data is less "available" and therefore hopefully a bit safer.

But be aware, the result is not two entities, but one entity (containing all data) and a value object which only contains the reduced data set of the entity.